Specific Ordering in Staked Bar Chart
I am trying to make a stacked bar chart with the following code described below.
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Generate artificial data
set.seed(123)
deciles <- rep(1:10, 2)
variable <- rep(c("cars", "bicyclis"), each = 10)
value <- runif(20, min = 0, max = 100)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(deciles, variable, value)

df$variable <- factor(df$variable, levels = c("cars", "bicyclis"))


  ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(deciles), y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") +  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("royalblue", "red"))


What I don't like about this bar chart is that the ordering is not what I expected. Namely, the data for cars, which are shown in blue, I want to be displayed first, while the data for bicycles, which are shown in red, I want to be displayed second.
Can someone help me solve this problem so that the data for cars are shown first and then the data for bicycles is shown?

First of all, if you want a stacked bar chart use position="stack". Additionally, you can reverse the order of the stack using reverse=TRUE (or by reversing the order of the levels of your factor):
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(deciles), y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("royalblue", "red"))



Look Forecats library if you want also to have a custom order, instead of just reversing the order you get (can be usefull with 3+ variables).
Also you should use tidyr instead of reshape2 as they recommend.
